# sort row by date in a column vba

Tags: vba, date, sorting, excel, autofilter

I Am trying to make my data sort each row by the date occuring in the N column.  Right now it is only sorting the n column by istelf with out changeing around any other information.  **How do I re-Write my code so that the whole row will move as opposed to just the single cell in that row?**

```
 Sub SortByDate()
 Dim rSortRange As Range
 Dim ws As Worksheet

 Set ws = Sheets("Copy")
 Set rSortRange = ws.Range("N11", "N111")
 rSortRange.Sort Key1:=ws.Range("N11"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Key2:=Range("N20"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
            Key3:=Range("N29"), Order3:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, _
            DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:=xlSortNormal
 End Sub
```

Got It with the following macro code

```
 Sub SortByDate()
 Dim rSortRange As Range
 Dim ws As Worksheet

 Set ws = Sheets("Copy")
 Set rSortRange = ws.Range("N11", "N111")
 rSortRange.Sort Key1:=ws.Range("N11"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Key2:=Range("N20"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
            Key3:=Range("N29"), Order3:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, _
            DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:=xlSortNormal
 End Sub
```

Sometimes I forget how easy it is to just record a macro!

Comment: is it too hard for you to show a piece of your sheet? You can get the entire data range, then sort it by sorting the Date column.

Comment: Record a Macro. I can give you the code but I want you to try it first ;)

Comment: @David  Please add your answer as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

```
  Sub SortByDate()
  Dim rSortRange As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheet

  Set ws = Sheets("Copy")
  Set rSortRange = ws.Range("N11", "N111")
  rSortRange.Sort Key1:=ws.Range("N11"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Key2:=Range("N20"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
        Key3:=Range("N29"), Order3:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, _
        DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:=xlSortNormal
  End Sub
```